# Upload to blob through SFTP in UTF-8 format

Tags: python, utf-8, sftp, azure-blob-storage, polybase

I am uploading some flat files to blob storage through SFTP. I need to convert them to UTF-8 format as I am using polybase. Is it possible to convert the files from ANSI to UTF-8 prior to uploading to blob.  I am using python to upload, but unable to convert to UTF-8. Please advise. Thank you

Below is the code I have used

```
blockSize = 1048576 
with codecs.open("your ANSI source file.txt","r",encoding="mbcs") as sourceFile: 
    with codecs.open("Your UTF-8 output file.txt","w",encoding="UTF-8") as targetFile: 
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(blockSize) 
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)
```

Comment: Convert to UTF-8 from what? Can you share a sample of the file, your code, and the error you get trying to encode as UTF-8?

Comment: @jordanm, I want to convert text files that are in ANSI to UTF-8. I have tried some sample code from internet but it is not converting them to UTF-8. Below is the code I have used.                                                               
blockSize = 1048576
with codecs.open("your ANSI source file.txt","r",encoding="mbcs") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open("Your UTF-8 output file.txt","w",encoding="UTF-8") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(blockSize)
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)

Comment: Please put the code in your post, so you can format it properly.

Comment: @lenz, I have the added the code in my question above

Comment: The code looks alright. Can you be more specific about how you are unable to convert? Is the output different from what you expect? Is there an exception? If so, please include the full traceback.

Comment: I have 100 files each one around 1GB. It is taking forever to run to convert atleast one file. Is there an easy to convert files of such size?

Comment: Using your code, it took me 15s to process a 1.7G file. Do you read or write through a network?

Comment: It looks like downloading the files from SFTP server to local system is taking too long. It is stopping after downloading 35MB. Is it possible to convert the files in blob storage to UTF-8 without downloading them locally?

Comment: You cannot convert encoding of a file over SFTP protocol. You have to download to local machine, convert and reupload. Of course, you might have a different interface to the storage in addition to SFTP, that may allow the in-place conversion, but we cannot know that.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your reply. Is it possible to convert them to UTF-8 after uploading them into Blob storage. I mean directly accessing the files from container, converting them to UTF-8 and replacing the files in the container?